# Accessing special glyphs in a font with xeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, fontspec

The Palatino Sans Family contains a special font for arrows that I'd like to use from `xeLaTeX`.

The Windows font preview shows examples using the German sentence "Franz jagt im komplett verwahrlosten Taxi durch Bayern":

[image: Windows font preview]

However I get only "?" in the PDF if I try the same sentence from LaTeX. So the questions is, how can I get an overview of all symbols in the font and how can I access the different characters?

```
% !TEX TS-program = xeLaTeX
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,ngerman]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{xkeyval,polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[spelling=new]{german}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{blindtext}


\newfontface\ultralightarrows{Palatino Sans Com Ultra Light Arrows}

\begin{document}

{\ultralightarrows Franz jagt im komplett verwahrlosten Taxi durch Bayern} 

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: FontForge (http://fontforge.org/) can be installed on Windows, and it gives much more information about a font than does the previewer you’re using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way, under Windows, is to use `Nexus Font`. You can ask to see the characters table of a font, classified by (UTF8) category  (`basic latin`, `subscripts and superscripts`, `arrows`, &c). Within one click you obtain a view of a given glyph, its (hexa)decimal code, the opentype exact name of the font,  and you can copy it to your (unicode) editor.

Here is a snapshot:

[image]

For the interested people, a link is [here](http://www.xiles.net/nexusfont/)

Answer (score 2):

I don't have the [Palatino... Arrows](http://www.linotype.com/3201/palatinosans.html) font on my computer, but I can show you how to retrieve glyphs from the [Code2000](http://web.archive.org/web/20101122142710/http://code2000.net/code2000_page.htm) font even if you cannot type them.

Next to common typing and copying+pasting from the Internet resources, we can use `\char` command and the glyph's octal, decimal or hexadecimal value. It is usually easy to retrieve such a value, e.g. by `charmap` program on Windows and Ubuntu. The common value is the hexadecimal one and we can spot form of U+HHHH, e.g. U+8361. In this example I show one CJK unified ideograph to demonstrate its use.

```
%! {xe|lua}latex mal-palatino.tex
% http://web.archive.org/web/20101122142710/http://code2000.net/code2000_page.htm
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontface\codett{Code2000}
\begin{document}
Text before {\codett 荡\char33633\char'101541\char"8361} text after.
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]